# Optimize form (containing .png backgrounds) loading in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, optimization, png

My problem is that I have an application developed in C# and before adding .png backgrounds all the forms are loading smoothly. After adding the backgrounds, the forms are loading much more difficult than before.

What can I possibly do in order to avoid the slow loading of the forms?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried loading all pngs during application load time?

Comment: what is the `BackGroundImageLayout` value in your case, try setting it to `None`

Comment: Please add more information how the backgrounds are loaded (from resources? from disk?) and how your forms are created (only when needed? preloaded?).

Comment: @SirViver - The backgrounds are loaded from resources and only when needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a timer to your form with a delay. Then load the PNGs in the tick event (as well as disabling the timer). That way the form would appear straight-away, but take a few seconds to show the PNG.

You could also try loading the PNGs in the Form_Shown event, although i'm not sure if that occurs after the GUI is displayed.

A final option could be, if appropriate, to load the forms before they're needed.

Answer (score 0):

Png format is faster than jpg and bmp.but you must load them at application startup.

```
Image Backgrund1 = Image.FromFile(@"MyFile1.png");
...
..
.
```

And in the load event set them to background;

```
this.BackgroundImage = Background1
```

Did you test it?

Also you can compress your images with some software such as photoshop -> Save for Web.
It

Comment: The image is already compressed. I will to try to load it at application startup and then wait to see what the result does look like. :)